# Which version of eclipse supports STS plugins?

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-jee

I have eclipse-jee-neon-3. I tried to install STS (Spring tool suit plugin) from eclipse marketplace but it's not showing STS plugins. Can anyone please tell which version of eclipse will support STS plugins or how to run spring-boot application on eclipse-jee-neon-3.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is too old. 13 releases and 5 years behind.

Comment: Please, before you ask, make sure that you have not missed to upgrade. The many questions referring to outdated software make it harder to find answers to real problems on Stack Overflow. Such questions are also not helpful as feedback to improve the open source software you are using for free. Therefore, there is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can look on the [Spring Tools Suite 3 page](https://github.com/spring-projects/toolsuite-distribution/wiki/Spring-Tool-Suite-3) but all the listed distributions require much newer versions of Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse extensions are available from the Eclipse marketplace for the most recent Eclipse versions and I would strongly recommend to use the latest Eclipse release as a base.

Eclipse JEE Neon is way too old to be supported here.

If you are required to stay on Eclipse Neon (for whatever reason), the latest release that supported that version of Eclipse was STS 3.9.4 and you could use this p2 repo URL to install it manually into an Eclipse from back then:

https://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.9.4.RELEASE/e4.6

But keep in mind that this version is not supported anymore and there isn't even a Spring Tools 4 version around that is compatible with Eclipse Neon (from 2016).